# Dúvida sobre z-index em divs separadas

Tags: css, z-index

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
.div1{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
.div2{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1
}
```

A `.div2` possui uma imagem que fica em cima da `.div1`, alguns pixels apenas.

O que acontece é que na `.div1` eu tenho um menu *dropdown* que está como padrão `display:none`, quando eu passo o mouse nele, ele fica `display:block` e z-index:3, só que esse `z-index` não fica acima da `.div2` pois ele está dentro da `.div1` que tem `z-index` menor, tem alguma solução para isso?

Comment: Ainda a pouco tempo tive esse problema, o que eu fiz foi deslocar o dropdown para fora da div, mas coloca-lo no mesmo sitio.

Comment: Verdade cara, fiz aqui e funcionou. Pena que perdi as referências de `position:relative` que tinha usado para centralizar 100% sem usar `margin`

Comment: Estava com o mesmo problema resolvi colocando o aributo position:fixed; na div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

z-index é um formigueiro. O melhor é realmente colocar o elemento que vai ficar por cima do lado de fora. Coloque janelas modals e prompts dentro do `<body>` para evitar conflitos.

Para entender melhor o porquê deste problema, vamos dar uma olhada em como funciona o z-index:

Adaptado do [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context):

- Atribuir um valor de z-index em um elemento cria um contexto de "empilhamento".
- Contextos de empilhamento podem estar contidos em outros contexto. Juntos eles criam uma hierarquia de contextos de empilhamento.
- Cada contexto é completamente independente de seus irmãos: apenas elementos descendentes são considerados quando o empilhamento é processado.
- Cada contexto de empilhamento é contido em si mesmo: após o conteúdo de um elemento ser empilhado, o elemento inteiro é considerado na ordem do contexto de empilhamento do pai.

Complicou, não é?

Vamos dar uma olhada nesta estrutura:

```
            z-index
div A       2
 |--div AA  1
 |--div AB  2

div B       1
 |--div BA  3
 |--div BB  4
```

Neste esquema div A tem z-index 2 e B tem z-index 1. Todas as divs dentro de Div B também terão z-index 1 quando comparadas com a Div A e suas divs filhas.
Os valores 3 e 4 de BA e BB só são válidos entre si, pois estão no mesmo contexto (nível).

Uma forma de "quebrar" a estrutura é atribuir um valor negativo ao z-index de uma div filha, mas note que essa abordagem não funciona no IE 6/7.

Comment: Vou tentar informar um z-index negativo, creio ser a solução. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Use position:relative na div ou ul que você quer que fique por cima.
position:relative por si só já faz com que o elemento "suba" um nível na sua página.